# TMG - Reverse proxy certificate mismatch

Tags: ssl, certificate, proxy

I have the web site rule set up but I am getting a certificate mismatch error. I have setup the rule using this walkthrough: [1] http://microsoftguru.com.au/2010/08/08/how-to-configure-reverse-proxy-using-forefront-tmg-2010-step-by-step/ (I'm aware of the typos)

As a test I have already established a working rule without using https and that seems to work fine. I am somewhat new to TMG and SSL/Certs so it could be that there is something wrong with my certs. I am using a server in my domain as a CA (Win2003) and I have not had issues with other internal sites.

Comment: While this is about an encryption product it may be a better fit for our sister site for IT professionals [ServerFault]. They will want more information about what you did and what errors you are receiving. I've asked a moderator about moving it for you, so please don't feel the need to repost.

Answer (score 0):

The Common Name of the SSL certificate assigned to your publishing rule must match the host header that you're publishing it as.

Also worth noting that you can have a different SSL certificate on the published server itself. So, for example you might be serving internal/VPN clients using an internal address with an SSL certificate issued by your domain CA, but publishing the server on the Internet using an SSL certificate provided by an Internet CA.